# Spring Integration enrich/transform message using Rest call

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-http

In Spring Integration, I have message like following :

```
{
  "name":"House",
  "attributeIds": [1,3,5]
}
```

I need to enrich/transform this message using some Rest Service, which will give me the attribute values.

For example `http://restservice.com/attributes?id=1,3,5` will answer me with

```
{"attributes": [
  {"id": 1, "value":"Waterproof"},
  {"id": 3, "value":"SoundProof"},
  {"id": 5, "value":"Concrete"}
]}
```

And the final object should look like this:

```
{
  "name":"House",
  "attributes": [
    {"id": 1, "value":"Waterproof"},
    {"id": 3, "value":"SoundProof"},
    {"id": 5, "value":"Concrete"}
  ]
}
```

How can this be achieved?

Should it be like this? https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=273&v=DHPsWDgEUXg

InboundAdapter -> Enricher -> Request Channel -> Service Activator -> Enricher -> Outbound Adapter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed a typical task for [Content Enricher](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/message-transformation.html#payload-enricher).

So, what you need is to deserialize that incoming JSON into a plain `Map`. Use a `request-payload-expression="payload.attributeIds"` to have that list of `ids` as a payload for sub-flow request.

A subscriber on the `request-channel` could be just simple Spring Integration [HTTP Outbound Gateway](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/http.html#http-outbound) to call that REST service and get an `attributes` message back.
This gateway can just come without an `output-channel` to produce its result back into a `content-enricher` via `replyChannel` header.

When this reply message comes to the `content-enricher`, a simple `<int:property name="attributes">` can be used to populate that new option in the request `Map`.

Afterwards you can remove an `attributeIds` key from that map and serialize it back to `JSON` if needed.

**UPDATE**

Here is a sample how it could be possible with Java DSL and Spring Boot: https://github.com/artembilan/sandbox/tree/master/spring-integration-enricher

Comment: If it is not too much, can you please give an example how it would look like with Java DSL? May be not working, but aproximate.
Can it be done using one IntegrationFlow?

Comment: Yes, it can be. I’ll prepare some Boot app today for you

Comment: Please, find an UPDATE in my answer.